# Modularity: unbundling swagger-ui from swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've recently proposed the use of swashbuckle to integrate swagger in our web-apis for the purpose of exposing an APIs functionality internally to our engineers. for our purposes swagger doesn't make sense in production since the apis are back-end..... being an enterprise environment the amount of APIs are large and I can foresee two major issues:

Size of assembly is around 2.6MB: Assume hundreds of apis build with swahbuckle integrated suddenly the size of all our apps has increased by 4.5 times. An unreasonable hit. Looking at the swashbuckle.core i suspect the bulk of the size is from swagger-ui being bundled. Would it be possible to unbundle swagger-ui from swashbuckle and instead allow swagger-ui to be added through a separate nuget package.

Bundled swagger-ui within swashbuckle has each and every api having its own instance of swagger-ui. Any customization made to swagger-ui has no effect to other projects unless one also makes that changes to every single api project increasing the effort and reducing maintainability chances. We are hosting swagger-ui centrally and make customization to allow for devs to try their swagger implementation locally (localhost) so are greatly effected by swashbuckle integrating swagge-ui and would've been significantly better off having the option to pull swagger-ui through a separate nuget package optionally.

Is there anything in pipeline to address the above or is our best chance to simply fork and move ahead at the cost of having to maintain it?

Answer (score 0):

[Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) is available as a single assembly in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Core/), which is pretty big as you mentioned.

It actually bundles **all necessary libraries** used to render *Swagger-UI* from within the assembly (e.g. jQuery, BackBone...)

Downloading Swashbuckle [directly from Github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/archive/master.zip) gives you the possibility to build it without any libs embedded, and ends up in the `Swashbuckle.Core/Bin` folder as a **130kb** file, 20 times smaller than the *nuget* version.

All features of *Swashbuckle* remain the same (appart of course of the render of Swagger-UI which gets completely broken, but that's not a issue if not using `EnableSwaggerUi` in `SwaggerConfig.cs` file)

In that case you just need to get the latest version of the [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) Github repo, without forking it (as it works straight out of it), which means **no maintenance**.